# How come there are 2 syntaxes for writing functions in a Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I noticed there are 2 different syntaxes for writing functions as part of an interface in Typescript. You can write either `functionName(): type` or `functionName: () => type`.

**Example**

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    print(): string;
    callback: () => string;
}

class SomeClass implements ISomeInterface {
    print() {
        return 'hi';
    }

    callback() {
        return 'works';
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these 2 ways of writing function signatures in the interface?